# Callback function in beforeRouteEnter is not triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have simple routes: /follower/:token/edit and /follower/new

When I move from the first one to the second one by $router.push('/follower/new') befoureRouteEnter hook is triggered but callback function inside 'next' function does not (problem does not exist when I go from different routes or reload page).

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    debugger; //is triggered
    next(vm => {
        debugger; //is not triggered
    })
}
```

Do you know what can be wrong?

Vue: 2.5.17
Vue-router: 3.0.1

Regards

Comment: It's an open issue in vue. If you use vue 2.5.17-beta.0 (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2255#issuecomment-411170463), the problem should be solved. Other "fixes" can be read here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are navigating between routes using the same component - vue tries to optimize by delivering a cashed version. I'm not sure if this is what you are experiencing – but you could try to force re-instantiation by adding a key value to your `<router-view>`.

A 'common' way to do this is to use $route.path

```
<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome :-). Side note this also solves route transitions not showing.